# L2TP + IPSec pfSense: can ping, no access

Tags: domain-name-system, vpn, ipsec, pfsense, l2tp

I am in process of setting up a L2TP + IPSec VPN (site to client) server based on pfSense.
While being connected to the VPN, I am able to ping any of the resources (e.g google.com, as well as anybody on the LAN). But when I try to open something in a web browser, no matter, Internet or LAN resource, it is impossible.
The network topology looks like this:
Client - - - Internet - - - Router1 --- pfSense (bridged virtual machine)
So, the pfSense is set up behind the firewall, Router1. I used [this manual](https://doc.pfsense.org/index.php/L2TP/IPsec) to set up pfSense.

Few other interesting things to be mentioned: nslookup works perfectly.

Router1 is exposed to the Internet, also, the computer running pfSense virtual machine has some services exposed to the Internet and while being connected to the VPN, I can access all that services, e.g. router1.com/vnc or router1.com/website, BUT, I cannot access the same services by local addresses, e.g. 10.0.0.10 - time out.

And, some addresses:
Router1 - 10.0.0.1/24
PC (pfSense host) - 10.0.0.10/24
pfSense - 10.0.0.11/24

"Server address" field in pfSense L2TP configuration - Router1 address
"Remote address range" in L2TP settings - 10.0.1.0/24
The only remote client address is 10.0.0.2/24, so it is in that subnetwork.

On pfSense VM I made firewall to work in "allow any-any" mode for testing purposes.

What I am asking for are some clues, how to troubleshoot this issue.
Thank you.

Comment: Check if you are forwarding port 80 and/or 443. Look at either wireshark or a tcpdump.

Comment: On which firewall should I check? Am I correct, I should set this in pfSense NAT?